# I just installed Android Studio and created a new project, it always came up with Error with gradle

Tags: android

My system is Win10 64-bit

```
Error:Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)


2015-12-29 18:57:09,522 [4021913]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'D:\Android\ASProjects\Sunshine-Version-2-1.01_hello_world' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'D:\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.8'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:360)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:332)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonDisappearedException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.handleDaemonDisappearance(DaemonClient.java:222)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:198)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:162)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:133)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:118)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:190)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:105)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-12-29 18:57:09,523 [4021914]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed) 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:438)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:348)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:164)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:332)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)

2015-12-29 18:57:09,524 [4021915]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2015-12-29 18:57:09,524 [4021915]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2015-12-29 18:57:09,524 [4021915]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'Sunshine-Version-2-1.01_hello_world' failed: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2015-12-29 18:57:09,582 [4021973]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2015-12-29 18:57:09,583 [4021974]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2015-12-29 18:57:09,587 [4021978]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2015-12-29 18:57:09,587 [4021978]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s.
```

Comment: Tell please version of Android Studio and Java SDK

Comment: Android Studio is 1.5 & java sdk 1.8

Comment: JDK8? Bingo. That's causes problem you need to change version to JDK7. Answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the issue is with your Java-version. Don't use the newest version until you would be sure it's fully supported.

I see two ways: first which I'm sure it works and second one which should works without downgrading JDK version in Android Studio. Choose yours.

#### RECOMMENDED: Downgrade your existing JDK8 to JDK7

First please install **Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 65 (JDK 7u65)**

Watch installation process to see where Java would be installed

After that follow these steps:

1. Go to Top Menu **File** and select **Project Structure**
2. Select the **SDK location** option on the left
   and enter the path of you JDK in the **JDK location**

[image: Android Studio SDK JDK location]

3. Change Java 8 SDK with JDK7.

After that restart Android Studio.

---

#### EXPERIMENTAL: Upgrading manual android-gradle to the newest one

1. In your project view, select `Gradle Scripts`
2. Open `gradle-wrapper.properties`
3. Change this line:

   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip

with

```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

4. Go to build.gradle (Project: your_app_name)
5. Change this line

   ```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
   ```

to this

```
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

6. Don't click `Sync Now`
7. From menu choose `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...`
8. Choose first option: `Invalidate and Restart`

Android Studio would restart. After this, it should work normally

Hope it help

Comment: Yes, I had simillar issues with it and I would recommend you to use JDK 7 until they would shown as deprecated. You have nothing to lose, just install another JDK version and change in settings. You could always change to latest one

Comment: In Windows JDK should be installed in `ProgramFiles/Java/jdk-xxx` folder

Comment: thanks a lot, this solved my problem on "error: gradle".

Comment: I have changed jdk version to 7 and plus distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file is set to https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip but it still shows the error