# android studio: nothing working getting different different errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to learn AS, but after struggling for 3 days no progress.
Using https://www.udacity.com for learning.

Trying the `hello world app` from there, got this error `Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'`.
I've worked in eclipse, but migrating from eclipse to AS looks very tough decision for me. I'm using cordova cli so far, now thinking to use AS.
While runing the app am not able to open `RUN TOOL` it show but is grey color(which is not clickable).
Downloaded new Gradle version (2.10), and set the path to that directory.But still showing Gradle version 2.2.1 in Project Structure.
Checked in stackoverflow as well, but nothing worked. Worst experieence.

Any body have idea what is going on, would be helpfull.

Android Studio 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest Gradle and Android Studio:
https://www.gradle.org/
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility

Go for more
[Android Studio Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' -- Error(17,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735646/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-error17-0)

Comment: My Problem Was Solved By Re installing The Both Android Studio and SDK

Comment: Correct, but that'll be my last choice. Bcuz it takes lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Udacity's Android courses are using the newest dependencies and AS version.

Please remove existing 1.2 version and upgrade it to 1.5.1 to get the fresh experience and less building problems

Be sure that you're using Oracle JDK7 not Java 8 SDK. It may cause some problems with Gradle

I recommend you also try to follow the steps in this post: [I just installed Android Studio and created a new project, it always came up with Error with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521023/i-just-installed-android-studio-and-created-a-new-project-it-always-came-up-wit/34521621?noredirect=1#comment56785116_34521621)

Have a question? Please free to ask

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Is AS is still unstable ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is better with every new version. With the latest version 1.5.1 Google fixed many bugs of 1.5 version, so there wasn't any new function, but better performance

Comment: But still is recommended to have more than 4GB RAM to work with it smoothly.

Comment: more than 4GB ? OK Thanks

Comment: On less than 4GB also it would work but I suppose that you would also like to use emulator (standard or Genymotion) and Chrome - they also eat some memory ;-)